# Joptionpane.showMessageDialog truncates title if its longer than message

Tags: java, joptionpane, messagedialog

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "short message", "Title has to be very longer than text, so long that title is cropped.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

use null instead of this if u are testing directly in main method.

As written in the above code , if joptionpane title is larger than message it gets cropped ? is there a way to set its size ?

I could not post its screenshot . Run the single line of code in your main function

Comment: `String txt= "ur text ";
  JTextArea jtextobject= new JTextArea(txt);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
   null, jtextobject, "Not Truncated!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`

Comment: @user3624028 this helps when a message is large. Unfortunately my title is larger than the message content itself.